# Optimus Alienware m14x external HDMI display?

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-optimus

Good evening.
I spent few hours browsing possible settings and solutions, but I'm running out of options so I would really appreciated any help. I got Alienware m14x with Optimus GT555M card and I would like to run dual screen with my laptop and my external HDMI screen. So far I only found the way how to run one or the other one. Is there really no way how to both of them together?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, and as far as I can tell there is no way to to run dual screen (e.g. extending desktop) with nvidia optimus. However, I found this tutorial http://www.webupd8.org/2012/08/get-hdmi-working-with-nvidia-optimus-on.html that allows you to run unity on one monitor and LXDE on the other. Of course, you are not limited to unity and LXDE but that is example used in tutorial. I hope this helps.